# Remove duplicate slashes and trailing slash

Tags: javascript

How to remove duplicate slashes and trailing slash using regex?
For example:
origin URL:

```
http://localhost:8080////app//user/login///
```

to

```
http://localhost:8080/app/user/login
```

Comment: `yourString.split(/\/{1,}/).filter(a=>!a.match(/^\s*$/)).join('/').replace(':/','://');` if ES6 is okay.

Comment: @Xufox I think it is a good question to show powerful regex, I don't understand why people vote against me and close my question. The closer must don't know the best answer!!!

Comment: Downvoting on this question is not appropriate. The question is not bad.

Comment: thanks. I don't want to use lots of `if` statement to do this, I want to find a best way, if `regex` could do this

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733 Read this.

Comment: @cezar Still doesn’t show enough research effort (what has he/she tried?).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a simple regex based approach.

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8080////app//user/login///';

var sanitized = url
           .replace(/^http\:\/\//, '') // remove the leading http:// (temporarily)
           .replace(/\/+/g, '/')       // replace consecutive slashes with a single slash
           .replace(/\/+$/, '');       // remove trailing slashes

url = 'http://' + sanitized;

// Now url contains "http://localhost:8080/app/user/login"
```

Comment: so we're not able to just use `regex` to achieve the goal?

Comment: Well, other than prefixing back the http:// at the end, regex is all there is.. :)

Comment: There are possibilities to create groups in the regex, but as regular expressions are not easy readable it will obfuscate the code. This solution is very simple and readable.

Comment: @techfoobar I think some `regex` are like utils, no need to change, but very useful in everywhere

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with using raw strings:

```
var result = String.raw`http://localhost:8080////app//user/login///`.replace(/\/+/g, "/");
```

The replace pattern matches every appearance of a slash once or more times and replaces it with a single slash.

Comment: but this regex will also replace the double slashes in 'http://', so how to solve this problem using regex ?

Comment: @Awakening Yes you are right, I wasn't thinking of it. So you have to follow the another answer that is splitting the input and takes out the part `http://`.

Comment: My solution also doesn't remove the trailing slash, instead it leaves a single slash at the end.

Comment: yeah, maybe can't do it only use `regex` , I think the `split` is the best way so far

Comment: @Awakening Which `split` one? The comment by me? Keep in mind that it uses `filter` which not all browsers support.

Comment: split is techfoobar's answer